# Divs side by side, width auto adjust

Tags: html, css

Hello Stack overflow users.
I'm in a bit of a struggle here, I have 4 divs.

I would like for div 4 to have it's width adjusted if the screen size is adjusted. Basically just stay within the other divs, and adjust.
Div 1,2 and 3 all have `position:fixed` to avoid them from moving when a user scrolls on the page.

But whatever I try, with `width:auto`ETC. div 4 keeps going the full length behind div 3. I have a margin set for it to pass by div 1's width length.

I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around this one, the code for my divs are listed below.

[image: Div Explanation]

```
.navbar-left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 325px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  height:auto;
}

.navbar-top{
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 z-index:1002;
}

.navbar-right{
  width: 365px;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
}
```

Div 4 is not listed, as the code did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0b2oy85/2/)

If you need to use position fixed (really I didn't understand why) you could use percentage for main div, and pixels for sidebars.

In main div to set the width use this:

width: calc(100% - 400px);
Where 400px is the sum of the width of your both sidebars

HTML

```
 <div clas="container">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.top {
  position: fixed;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
}
.main {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40px;
  background-color: grey;

}
.right {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code...

```
.div4{ width:calc(100% - 730px);
       background-color: green;
       margin:0 auto;
       position:relative;
       top:60px;}
```

where 730px is sum of left and right div widths...

Comment: @Codey93 sorry... the code is updated now. hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use percents for navbar-left, navbar-right and the middle portion.

Do not forget to set `top:60px` (height of navbar-top) for the left and right divs.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o8fu2o14/)</kbd>

```css
/* *CSS:* */

div {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar-top {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}
.navbar-left {
 position: fixed;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 60px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}
.navbar-right {
 position: fixed;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 60px;
 right: 0;
}
.myBody {
 width: 60%;
 margin: 60px auto 0px;
}
.navbar-top {
 background: blue;
}
.navbar-left {
 background: red;
}
.navbar-right {
 background: green;
}
.navbar-top {
 background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!-- **HTML:** -->
<div class="navbar-top">navbar-TOP</div>
<div class="navbar-left">navbar-LEFT</div>
<div class="navbar-right">navbar-RIGHT</div>
<div class="myBody"> My body lies over the ocean... hummmmm </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give each a width that will equal to 100%. Give left div  20% div 4 60% and right div 20%. Or, with existing code, give 4th div 100%.

Comment: This might be somewhat what I'm seeking towards, however I only wish for div 4 to be smaller when the screen region is lowered.

Comment: Also you could put 20% and give them a min-width of existing code. Don't  give min-width to 4th div, but give it 80%. Try playing around with that.

Comment: Cheers, I totally forgot about min-width.

Comment: Ahh. Hate when that happens. Haha